Split view on Android Studio not showing XML portion
Android studio will not show my the XML portion of the xml file. When viewing in split mode, only the preview is shown.
Image showing XML code not showing up
I've set the editor settings to all split but still doesn't work. Here is image of my android studio. I've invalidated my file caches, sync project file gradle, updated android studio to latest (Koala version).

Text/Design Tab Missing Android Project

Does it answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78494408/11512499
